# Using a c# class and vb class on one aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an assignment where I have to use c# and vb in the same project.  After searching it seemed a website would be best for this in visual studios and it had been going relatively well.  I ran into a problem when I was asked to have a label and a button.  The Button is suppose to use vb code and the label is suppose to use c#.  My initial response was to create two aspx pages and add the button to one and the label to the other and then no problems really came up.  However I'm wondering if it's possible to use the same aspx page for both items and still have the vb coded button and c# coded label?  If it is possible how do you do that sort of thing?

All insight is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the purpose of this assignment to make you dislike your instructor or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a `UserControl`.  The user control can be written in either C# or VB, and then it can be added to an application page that's coded in the other language.  When using a User Control, from the outside, you don't need to know if it was written in C# or VB, and it's designed to go into a page and play nicely with other controls, so you don't need to try to figure out how to combine two pages together in the browser.

Comment: I'm a little unsure of how exactly UserControl works.  Any advice on good tutorials?  I was able to add one but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to put in it.

Comment: @user1974576 Think of it as a page that goes inside of another page.

Answer (score 1):

A single project cannot contain code from more than 1 language. A solution can contain multiple projects. Each project can use any language that is available to you, so you can have a solution with multiple languages, but within a single project, you can only have 1 language.

Comment: That's not quite true.  Code embedded in the markup of an aspx or ascx page can be either C# or VB.

Comment: That makes sense, I never thought of that. I'll probably get yelled at for this, but the reason I didn't know is that I personally consider code blocks like that to be misplaced. The code-behind is where that belongs, but you are technically correct, it can go there. That would be a good extra credit on the test, why is it if you have a C# web project that you can't have VB.NET code in the code-behind, but you can in code blocks on an ASPX page. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you mean by `The Button is suppose to use vb code`. Does it mean that event handler for your button is written in `VB.NET` or it is written in `VB.NET` itself? Respectively for your `C#` label. If you want to use these languages to write one `*.aspx` answer is *no*. If these button and label are just custom controls written in `VB.NET` and `C#` answer is *yes* and check `Servy`'s answer.

Comment: All this answer really contains is some clarifying questions and a "check another answer".  It never answers the question.  The clarifying questions should just be comments, since you have no answer to go along with them.

Comment: I suggested the two situations, and reviewed them. After that I saw your question and decide to not repeat the information. If it is not SO way, I will notice it.